# ArcGIS Pro Global Scene Prohibitively Slow with Simple Data

Tags: arcgis-pro, arcscene, global-scene

I am trying to follow [this great blog by Heather Smith](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/mapping/exaggerate-your-perspective-view/) to create a perspective view in ArcGIS Pro. Yet, even with just a single vector polygon, the panning and overall navigation is prohibitively slow, to the point that I cannot even progress past the first step of "zoom to your area of interest" without it taking me an hour. My machine is no slouch (64-core processor) and Pro performs well, even with large datasets. I know ideally you need a good GPU for Pro, but I was informed my Windows has an advanced graphics card, even though this is what's displayed in my device manager:

[image]

What settings can I adjust to remedy this?

[This Esri help page](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/reference/best-practices-scene-performance.htm#:%7E:text=If%20you%20notice%20slow%20rendering,faces%20to%20improve%20rendering%20performance.) did not provide any useful info.